# Filtering data based on a list of keywords

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I have a dataframe of +- 130k tweets, alongside a label (1=positive, 0=negative). From this dataframe, I want to **extract** the tweets that are movie-related. To do this, I've come up with a list of movie-related words:

```
movie_related_words = ["movie", "movies", "watch", 
                       "watching", "film", "cinema", 
                       "actor", "video", "thriller", 
                       "horror", "dvd", "bluray", "soundtrack", 
                       "director", "remake", "blockbuster"]
```

After some pre-processing the tweets in the dataframe are tokenized, so that the text column of my dataframe contains *lists of tweets*, where *every word* is a seperate list element. For your reference, please find three random elements of my dataframe below:

```
[well, time, for, bed, 500, am, comes, early, nice, chatting, with, everyone, have, a, good, evening, and, rest, of, the, weekend, whats, left, of, it]
[tekkah, defyingsantafe, umm, dont, forget, that, youre, all, gay, socialist, atheists]
[s, mom, nearly, got, ran, over, by, a, truck, on, her, bike, and, dropped, her, work, bag, with, all, her, information, which, was, then, stolen, fb]
```

I want to **filter** the tweets, when **any** word of a given tweet (so an element of a list) is **in** the movie_related_words list, i want to *retain* that observation, and if not I want to *discard* it.

I have tried applying a lambda expression like so:

```
def filter_movies(text):
    movie_filtered = "".join([i for i in text if i in movie_related_words])
    return movie_filtered

twitter_loaded_df['text'] = twitter_loaded_df['text'].apply(lambda x : filter_movies(x))
```

But it gives me a strange result. Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. A pythonic/efficient way will result in eternal love from me for you. My hope is that there exists some kind of pandas function for this purpose, but I have not yet found it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
MOVIE_RELATED_WORDS = set(["movie", "movies", "watch", 
                           "watching", "film", "cinema", 
                           "actor", "video", "thriller", 
                           "horror", "dvd", "bluray", "soundtrack", 
                           "director", "remake", "blockbuster"])

def contains_movie_word(words):
    return any(word in MOVIE_RELATED_WORDS for word in words)

is_movie_related = df['text'].apply(contains_movie_word)

df = df[is_movie_related]  # Filter using boolean series
```

The advantages of this approach are:

1. It short-circuits (returns early) as soon as a single movie-related word is found in a given tweet.
2. It is `O(N_tweet_words)` for each row in the dataframe, since set lookups are `O(1)` on average.

Example:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'text': [['Hello', 'world'], ['Great', 'movie'], ['Bad', 'weather']]})
```

Here, `df` is:

```
             text
0  [Hello, world]
1  [Great, movie]
2  [Bad, weather]
```

After applying the solution, `is_movie_related` is:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: text, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! After some close investigation, the problem seems to be something with my dataframe; when I check your dataframe by using `print(type(df['text'][0]))`, it print that the type is "list" which is correct. When I do this on my dataframe, It gives me back that it is of type "String". Even though my data looks exactly *like* a list, it seems to be a string for pandas. I have no idea why this is or how to convert it.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible that your data is not in the form you expect. If you simply assign `v = df.loc[0, ‘text’]`, what exactly is the type and value of `v`? If it’s not a list or set, you’ll need to back up and fix that issue.

Comment: I think I managed to isolate the issue. Everything is fine, and indeed my dataframe contains lists of words (As expected). However, I cached the results to a CSV-file in between by using the to_csv method of pandas. When I try to load the results back in, Suddenly it sees all the lists as being "Strings". Very strange.

Comment: That is not strange at all.  If a dataframe has an object column where each element is a non-trivial Python data structure, such as a list, dictionary, or set, how is it supposed to write that complicated data structure to a CSV field?  I would bet your CSV contains strings with escaped commas.  Perhaps pandas would do something sensible if you wrote your datafame to JSON instead (i.e. write each list element as a JSON array).

Comment: You are right, there is no way for pandas to Infer these kinds of structures after writing to CSV! Stupid me! I removed all punctuation with pre-processing, so no escaped commas. What got me is that, after loading back from CSV the data still *looks* as if it is CSV, even though python sees it as a String. Sometimes it's the little mistakes that kill you. Thanks anyways

Comment: After I managed to isolate the issue, your solution works like a charm. Thx!

Comment: Do you by any chance know a better way to serialize pandas dataframes, where data structures are retained?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right, try:

```
twitter_loaded_df['movie_related'] = twitter_loaded_df['text'].map(lambda x: max([word in movie_related_words for word in x]))
```

It should add a column "movie_related" with *True/False* if any of these words are in your list.

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work; All the values in twitter_loaded_df['movie_related'] are False, While im sure there are movie related tweets in the dataset.

Comment: @Psychotechnopath In the 3 lists you gave as example, I don't see matches. Try to find a place that has a match, and that my solution really gives wrong *False*. Maybe it requires a small adjustment.

Comment: `['no', 'movie', 'times', 'for', 'sunday', 'rats', 'will', 'have', 'to', 'plan', 'tomorrow', 'i', 'guess', 'this', 'means', 'i', 'have', 'to', 'work', 'on', 'those', 'two', 'presentations', 'i', 'am', 'doing']` has an element which says "movie", but in your solution  `twitter_loaded_df['movie_related']` is still False.

Comment: @Psychotechnopath just run it, and it gave me *True* for that line. Are you sure that in the column 'text' you have a list of words? Maybe it's a list of lists or something?

Comment: We might be on to something here. If i use `twitter_loaded_df.dtypes`, I see my text column is of type "object". I think pandas automatically does this for String-like data; but maybe therefore 'regular' python code does not work when using a  pandas dataframe?